# Downloading SoilGrids data from WCS in R

Tags: gdal, r, gdal-translate, wcs

I am trying to download SoilGrids GeoTIFF data in R using WCS. I have followed the tutorial set up by ISRIC (https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/markdown/wcs_from_R.md).

I have had no issues with getting data to download in the past but for whatever reason, today I have been getting an error message when running the `gdal_translate()` function. I have included the code below (which does not differ very much from what is shown in the tutorial):

```
# Variable of Interest:
voi      <- "cec"
depth    <- "5-15cm"
quantile <- "Q0.5"

voi_layer <- paste(voi, depth, quantile, sep = "_")

# Variable necessary for WCS call
wcs_path <- paste0("https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/", voi, ".map")
wcs_service <- "SERVICE=WCS"
wcs_version <- "VERSION=2.0.1" # use 1.1.1 for gdal version < 2.3

# Set bounding box for download of TIFF (in Homolosine projection):
bb <- c(-13326040.540570, 7858775.724074, -11752986.098472, 7177452.780999)
igh <- "+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

wcs <- paste(wcs_path, wcs_service, wcs_version, sep = "&")

l1   <- newXMLNode("WCS_GDAL")
l1.s <- newXMLNode("ServiceURL", wcs, parent = l1)
l1.l <- newXMLNode("CoverageName", voi_layer, parent = l1)

# Save to local disk
xml.out = "./SoilGrids/sg.xml"
saveXML(l1, file = xml.out)

# Download raster as GeoTIFF (Warning: it can be large!)
file.out <- paste0("./SoilGrids/", voi_layer, ".tif")

gdal_translate(xml.out,
               file.out,
               tr = c(250, 250),
               projwin = bb,
               projwin_srs = igh, 
               co = c("TILED=YES","COMPRESS=DEFLATE","PREDICTOR=2","BIGTIFF=YES"),
               verbose = TRUE
)
```

The message shown after the `gdal_translate()` function is this:

```
Checking gdal_installation...
GDAL version 3.0.4
GDAL command being used: "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin\gdal_translate.exe" -tr 250 250 -projwin -13326040.54057 7858775.724074 -11752986.098472 7177452.780999 -of "GTiff" -projwin_srs "+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "PREDICTOR=2" -co "BIGTIFF=YES" "./SoilGrids/sg.xml" "./SoilGrids/cec_5-15cm_Q0.05.tif"
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.dbInput file size is 159246, 580340...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
NULL
```

The `ERROR1` line is new and seems to be causing the issue.
Any ideas?

---

Update:

The ERROR code shown in the example above does not seem to be causing any issues with the creation of the raster. When I load the raster in from the file created using `gdal_translate()` and try reproject it, setting `res = 30` in the `rasterProject()` function seems to change all values to `NA`. Code below:

```
rast <- raster(paste0("./SoilGrids/", voi_layer, ".tif"))
rast <- projectRaster(rast, 
                      res = 30, 
                      crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
                             +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

To fix this, I removed `res = 30` and replaced it with the disaggregate function before reprojecting (as below).

```
rast <- raster(paste0("./SoilGrids/", voi_layer, ".tif"))
crs(rast) <- igh
rast <- disaggregate(rast, fact = (250/30)) # original resolution = 250, desired resolution = 30
rast <- projectRaster(rast,
                      crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

Comment: try setting the PROJ_LIB environment variable to the location of  proj.db in your QGIS installation

Comment: @nmtoken thanks! I've seen this recommended on a number of other related posts with people having similar issues. Do you know how to do this in R?

Comment: You are running QGIS GDAL... command being used:... in your error

Comment: Do you have admin rights on the pc

Comment: @nmtoken I do not have admin rights on the PC I used in the example above (it was a work machine). However, I've just run the same code on my personal laptop resulting in a different error (ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: crs not found). Oddly enough, though, the correct raster is still being generated.

Comment: My personal laptop looks to be running it in OSGeo4W

Comment: You might try in QGIS > Settings > Options > System > Environment.

Comment: @nmtoken Thanks. I just checked the PROJ_LIB environment variable in QGIS and the value leads me to the correct folder in my program files. I can see the proj.db file there. Weird. 

The first error in the post above shows the path to the function as `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin\gdal_translate.exe` whereas the proj.db file is in `~\QGIS 3.10\share\proj`